# Importing rows from a sheet to another under condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to create a macro that : 
 * Activate the option " automatic calculation"
 * Delete all last rows
 * Add new rows from another sheet under a condition : import rows when the value of the first cell =X
I created the code below, the two first steps works welle but the third doesn't work.
Can someone explain me why ?

```
Sub refresh()
'
' refresh Macro
'
' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+y
'
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
Dim lngRow As Long

Set wksSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
Set wksDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque S")
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").ClearContents 'Works directly, without selection



lngRow = wksDest.Cells(wksDest.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 2 To wksSrc.Range("A" & wksSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  If wksSrc.Cells(i, 1) = "X" Then
    wksSrc.Range(wksSrc.Cells(i, 2), wksSrc.Cells(i, 20)).Copy

    wksDest.Range("B" & lngRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: your Rows.Count will be counting the same rows on the same sheet.  Where your macro implies it should be count rows from the different sheets (PTR & Analyse de risque).  Suggest you be explicit with which sheets rows you are counting.

Answer (score 0):

On first glance I'd guess you are nto specific enough for VBA. You do not define where VBA should work. So this way the whole code is always run on the visible sheet. You should always specify in which worksheet the code should run, else you will have unwanted side effects, like deleting stuff in the wrong worksheet.
Next you should omit using "select", which usually can be avoided and is slow. You should try something like:

```
Sub refresh()
'
' refresh Macro
'
' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+y
'
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
dim wksSrc as Worksheet, wksDest as Worksheet
Dim lngRow as Long

set wksSrc = 'your source worksheet, i.E. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque")
set wksDest= 'your destination worksheet i.E. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PTR")
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wksDest.Range("A6:AP1000").ClearContents 'Works directly, without selection

lngRow = wksDest.cells(wksDest.rows.count,2).end(xlup).row+1

For i = 2 To wksSrc.Range("A" & wksSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  If wksSrc.Cells(i, 1) = "X" Then
    wksSrc.Range(wksSrc.Cells(i, 1), wksSrc.Cells(i, 20)).Copy
    wksDest.Range("B" & lngRow).PasteSpecial    xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    lngRow=lngRow+1
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

See how you need to be specific on where to get the data from and where to put it? Without the defined worksheet Excel will always the active worksheet.

Added a row counter. Please be aware this one checks the last row in column "B" (column 2) and adds one, so the last row is kept. After each copy the coutner gets raised by one, to jump to the next column.

Added another specification of which sheet to use, that I forgot.

Comment: Thank you Blind Seer for your answer,but i still have a problem in the code. It imports all rows in the last row of the sheet one by one and after each paste it crushes the one before  and when it finishes i just have the last row of the other sheet ^pasted in the last row of the new sheet.

Comment: Added a few lines that should solve your problem. Sorry, didn't check for this error. Now it should always use the row below the last one.

Comment: The crush problem is solved but it always pastes at the end of the sheet many times .Maybe it is a problem of the loop

Comment: Please check again now. Can't find any reason why things are copied more than once, just forgot another wksSrc. It goes through from row 2 down to the last row and copies every time it finds an "X". Perhaps you should set a breakpoint and go through the code step by step to see if anything strange happens.